# How to proxy all requests except one specific folder?

Tags: nginx

I have the following configuration in one Nginx website:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.example.com;

    location /.well-known {}

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3009;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

My idea was to proxy all requests to a node application except the ones to folder /.well-known. But for some reason node is handling all requests.

What've I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I have my server configured with:

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
  default_type "text/plain";
  allow all;
  root /srv/www/acme/[domain];
}
```

That works for me (using certbot).

You can of course change the root location to anything you choose.

Comment: My mistake I thought that the response was the app index.html (it was before the configuration I posted here). But it was nginx default 404 blank page. Thank you.